# JavaScript callback is returned in different locations

Tags: javascript, callback

I defined a class and function inside that with callback. The function is called twice outside in two different files. Callback is returned to another function instead of being called file.

**I have defined a function in c.js as below**:

```
var  Demo = (function(){
    return {  
        load:function(x, callbackstatus){  
            //do something with X and return callback status  
            callbackstatus("Completed");   
        }    
    }
})();
```

**In file a.js, I have the code below:**

```
var statusA = function(value){  
   console.log("In A");  
}  
Demo.load(x, statusA);
```

**In file b.js, I have the code below:**

```
var statusB = function(value){   
   console.log("In B");   
}   
Demo.load(x, statusB);
```

Sometimes when I call `Demo.load(x, statusB)` in b.js, it returns the output as "In A".

Comment: *"I defined a class"* - No you didn't, you created an object. Anyway, are you saying all three JS files are included on the same page?

Comment: You're missing some brackets in the `Demo` function.

Comment: `Console.log`? what is `Console`? there's a `console` of course, but `Console`?

Comment: You've obviously tried to simplify the code for posting here, and left out the part that's causing the problem. Because there's no way the code you posted could have the problem you describe.

Comment: You have the `asynchronous` tag, but there's nothing asynchronous in the code here.

Comment: Don't use `status` as a top-level function name. It conflicts with `window.status`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Comment: Got it. But I didn't use status in actual code. Edited the question

Comment: @Amanda Is this all of the code? Nothing in this code would cause this to happen.